# How to make jupyter notebook select python2.7 by default?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I have both python 2 & 3 installed, but jupyter only sees python3.

My project runs using python2. How do I make jupyter give me choice btw both python versions?
[image: jj]

Comment: If you open jupyter with Anaconda Navigator you can select python engine in tab "Environments".

Comment: @Michal Lis, i did, it open cmd shell, i type "jupyter notebook" it does not work

Comment: I believe you open Anaconda Prompt. I propose gui-based solution with Anaconda Navigator not Anaconda Prompt.

Comment: @MichałLis, I do use gui based , here screenshot http://prntscr.com/l5yz8j

Comment: @MichałLis, it seems there is jupyter coming with anaconda, and another jupyter i can install with pip. i m doing this now

Comment: Ok, so only select python 2 version and open jupyter.

Comment: i m deleting anaconda, and installing it again